# How do i display data i have stored from a fetch request?

Tags: reactjs

So i have made a fetch request and stored the data into a const. I am having trouble accessing the data to display it.

```
const [itemDetails, setItemDetails] = useState([]);
```

This is the structure of data stored in itemDetails and i cant figure out how to display it.

```
item:
customerCount: 0
itemCatName: "Furniture - Photos/Paintings/Prints"
itemCost: 21.96
itemDescription: "Removable and repositionable with no sticky residue. Perfect for nurseries, apartments, dorm rooms, and businesses. Wall decal stickers are mess-free, no paint, no glue/paste, no residue."
itemID: 6
itemImage: "/Images/I/51vJQpTLP7L._AC_.jpg"
itemName: "Golf Cart Seniors Isolated Peel and Stick Wall Decals "
unitsSold: 0

customerList: Array(197)
[0 … 197]
0: {customerName: 'Joel Amess', email: 'immamess@gmail.com', primaryPh: '491592807', secondaryPh: null, addressLine1: '51 Prince Street', …}
1: {customerName: 'Jack Schlink', email: 'jackschlink@outlook.com', primaryPh: '0420194047', secondaryPh: null, addressLine1: '34 Round Drive', …}
2: {customerName: 'Jett Freeleagus', email: 'jettfree@gmail.com', primaryPh: '0489847578', secondaryPh: null, addressLine1: '48 Magnolia Drive', …}
3: {customerName: 'Brock Mills', email: 'bmills@gmail.com', primaryPh: '0488806371', secondaryPh: null, addressLine1: '13 Taylor Street', …}
4: {customerName: 'Koby Wiedermann', email: 'koby@gmail.com', primaryPh: '0420029236', secondaryPh: null, addressLine1: '36 Reynolds Road', …}
5: {customerName: 'Eve Coane', email: 'eevee@gmail.com', primaryPh: '0489973669', secondaryPh: null, addressLine1: '22 SWestern Australianston Street', …}
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: This is my code im trying to run but it gives me itemDetails.map is not a function. the itemDetails has all the right data i just cant display it...

```
function ItemDetails() {
  //variable to store data passes from handlePageChange
  const location = useLocation();
  const itemID = location.state.itemID;
  const year = location.state.year;
  const [itemDetails, setItemDetails] = useState([]);
  console.log(itemDetails);


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchItemDetails = async () => {
      if(year != null && itemID != null){
        try {
          const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:56384/api/RecallDetail?itemID=${itemID}&year=${year}`);
          setItemDetails(await response.json());
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('Failed to fetch from Amazon DB', error);
        }
      } else {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:56384/api/RecallDetail?itemID=${itemID}`);
          setItemDetails(await response.json());
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('Failed to fetch from Amazon DB', error);
        }
      }   
    };
    fetchItemDetails();
  }, []);

  return (  
    <div>
    <div>
    <h1>Recall Information</h1>
    <p>Product:</p>
    <p>Unit Cost:</p>
    <p>Description</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Contact Details</th>
          <th>Addrress Line</th>
          <th>Total Cost</th>
          <th>Units Sold</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {itemDetails.map(item => {
                return (
                    <tr >
                    <td>{ item.customerList.customerName }</td>
                    <td>{ item.customerList.email }</td>
                    <td>{ item.customerList.addressLine1 }</td>
                    <td>${ item.customerList.totalCost }</td>
                    <td>{ item.customerList.unitsSold}</td>
                    </tr>
                );
                })}
            </tbody>


      </table>
    </div>

    <NavLink to="/" activeClassName="active">
        Go Back
    </NavLink>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you show your current attempt `codes` to display the data

Comment: edited my post top show my code

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
    fetch(URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setUsers(json));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Test </h1>
      {users.map((user) => {
        return <div key={user.id}>{user.title} </div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You can `useState` for storing a data and use `useEffect` hook for calling API's. You can use [fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch) or [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) packages for that.

**Example:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
    fetch(URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setUsers(json));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Test </h1>
      {users.map((user) => {
        return <div key={user.id}>{user.title} </div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Dependencies argument of `useEffect` is `useEffect(callback, dependencies)`

Let's explore side effects and runs:

**Not provided: the side-effect runs after every rendering.**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs after EVERY rendering
  });  
}
```

**An empty array []: the side-effect runs once after the initial rendering.**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs ONCE after initial rendering
  }, []);
}
```

**Has props or state values `[prop1, prop2, ..., state1, state2]`: the side-effect runs only when any dependency value changes.**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent({ prop }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs ONCE after initial rendering
    // and after every rendering ONLY IF `prop` or `state` changes
  }, [prop, state]);
}
```

Comment: ive already done my fetch request and the data is stored in itemDetails. i want to display the data and thats what im having trouble with

Comment: Unless there is something axios does that fetch doesn't, there is no point adding an extra dependency to your project.

Comment: Update my answer. Please check

Answer (score 0):

You can map the `itemDetails` array and then return some HTML element for each item.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const SomeComponent = () => {
    const [itemDetails, setItemDetails] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Do the fetching and setItemDetails here...
    });

    return (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            {itemDetails.map((item) => (
                <span>{item.customerName}</span>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

The `map` method creates an array from the items returned by the provided callback function. So here we are just directly creating an array of span elements that render inside the div.